# How to specify starting value of index in Groovy's eachWithIndex method?

Tags: loops, groovy, closures

When using Groovy's [eachWithIndex](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Looping) method the index value starts at 0, I need it to start at 1.  How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you need it to start at one?

Comment: @cdeszaq because I'm using it to build URLs to files, and the file names end with numbers starting at 1, not 0.

Comment: @typoknig why can't you just calculate `index + 1`

Comment: @Don Guess I could, just trying to be more concise. I thought I was just missing something because changing the default value of an index seems like something Groovy (or any language) should allow me to do.

Comment: @typoknig you could always use an old skool for-loop if you really want to control the loop variable, but if it's conciseness you're after, that won't help you much

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The index will always start from `0`

Your options are:

1) Add an offset to the index:

```
int offs = 1
list.eachWithIndex { it, idx ->
  println "$it @ pos ${idx + offs}"
}
```

2) Use something other than `eachWithIndex` (ie: transpose a list of integers starting at 1 with your original list, and then loop through this)

3) You can also use default parameters to hack this sort of thing in...  If we pass `eachWithIndex` a closure with 3 parameters (the two that `eachWithIndex` is expecting and a third with a default value of `index + 1`):

```
[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ].eachWithIndex { item, index, indexPlusOne = index + 1 ->
  println "Element $item has position $indexPlusOne"
}
```

We will give the output:

```
Element a has position 1
Element b has position 2
Element c has position 3
```

Comment: I like the hack, but not the fact that it is necessary.  Seems like we should be able to say index = 1.  Do you think it would be better to do the hack you suggested or a standard for loop?

Comment: I would probably do option 1, and just add `1` to the index passed from `eachWithIndex`.  A standard for loop would be faster though if your list is immense...  If not, I'd go for the readability of option 1

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use eachWithIndex at all, a for loop with .indexed(1) will be more elegant/readable:

```
for (item in ['a','b','c','d','e'].indexed(1)) {
  println("element $item.key = $item.value")
}
```

outputs:

```
element 1 = a
element 2 = b
element 3 = c
element 4 = d
element 5 = e
```

caveat -- indexed(n) is only available in Groovy 2.4.0 onwards

Comment: This should be the top answer for Groovy 2.4.0. But it seem this version is too new, so lots of system don't have it. Quick check here gave me 1.8.x, quite a surprise actually...

Answer (score 2):

What about just using a [Range](http://www.groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#Collections-Ranges)?

```
def offset = 1
def arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
def len = arr.size() - 1
arr[offset..len].eachWithIndex{n,i -> println "${i+offset}:$n"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some metaprogramming hackery as well:

```
def eachWithMyIndex = { init, clos ->
    delegate.eachWithIndex { it, idx -> clos(it, idx + init) }
}
List.metaClass.eachWithMyIndex = eachWithMyIndex    

[1,2,3].eachWithMyIndex(10) {n, idx ->  println("element $idx = $n") }
```

gives output:

```
element 10 = 1
element 11 = 2
element 12 = 3
```